# What is the infinitesimal work done when the force is given by the gradient of a scalar function that depends both on position AND time?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, differentiation

The title is slightly confusing but I didn't know how else to phrase my question.
Basically, this is the situation:

When the force applied to a particle is given by the gradient of a scalar function that depends explicitly on JUST the position of the particle, that force is conservative and $T+V$ is conserved.
However, if it depends explicitly on both position AND time, then $T+V$ is still defined but not conservative.

In my notes, this is proven:

$$F(r(t),r)\cdot \dot{r} dt = -\nabla V(r(t),t)\cdot \dot{r}dt = \left( -\frac{dV(r(t),t)}{dt}+\frac{\partial V(r(t),t)}{\partial t}\right)dt$$

What I don't understand is the second line, working it out a few times but I never get the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know about the notion of *total derivative*. See (probably) any book on mechanics or calculus, or for a quick overview the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative

$$ \frac{d}{dx}V(f(x),x) = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial f}\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$
That is the definition of the total derivative of $V$ wrt. $x$. It utilizes the chain rule. I believe you got it from here!